# channel.onDeviceReady.state values

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an app which has a loop waiting for `channel.onDeviceReady.state` to get to 2 and never gets there. Where do I find out what different values of `channel.onDeviceReady.state` mean?

The code is:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (channel.onDeviceReady.state != 2) {
        console.log('1deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.');
        logUnfiredChannels(platformInitChannelsArray);
        logUnfiredChannels(channel.deviceReadyChannelsArray);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: With a technique called debugging.

Comment: Well... it would be useful to know what the different values mean.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question.